# Strong reference in Vapor Hello sample

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting, vapor

While playing with Vapor Hello sample (https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/getting-started/hello-world/), I've encountered this:

```
public func routes(_ router: Router) throws {
    ...
    let todoController = TodoController()
    router.get("todos", use: todoController.index)
    router.post("todos", use: todoController.create)
    router.delete("todos", Todo.parameter, use: todoController.delete)
}
```

As we can see here, `todoController` is a local variable of a global `routes` function. And it should be immediately deallocated after leaving its scope, because reference to it passed to nowhere. References to members are passed, but it's not how ARC works according to my level of understanding. However, `todoController` is alive during the whole program execution. Where is the trick here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`todoController.index` is a closure which captures `self`, which is holding a strong reference to `todoController`.

This, `todoController` will persist so long as the `router` has these `get`/`post`/`delete` handlers registered.

Comment: But `index` is just a "return Todo.query(on: req).all()", does it capture `self` indirectly?

Comment: @faviomob All instance methods capture `self`. That's what makes them instance methods.

Comment: Uh oh, I somehow mixed them up with closures there, but they are methods. Now it's clear.

Comment: @faviomob Well instance methods *are* closures. All functions in Swift are closures, in that they can capture and keep alive any external references.

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html "Global and nested functions, as introduced in Functions, are actually special cases of closures." - that's all I could find in swift docs. Couldn't you provide a link where Apple explicitly says that instance methods are also closures?

Comment: I'm not going to bother searchign for docs, but try just doing `print(someObj.someMethod), and see what you get.